# Remove/Delete a layer or layergroup with mouse click

Tags: openlayers

I add a ol.layer.Vector OR ol.layer.Group with a mouse click in the map. By a new mouse click should the layer removed/deleted AND a new layer should be add. etc.

I have search and search and don't found a **simple** methode. There is all complicated or don't work, or with Ajax or JQuery (i don't use it).

Then i use this and that is the best solution:

```
if (map.getLayers().array_.length > 1) {
map.getLayers().array_.pop();
}
```

That works absolutelly **perfect** and is absolutelly **simple**. OpenLayers does not seem to have such a simple solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Properties ending with underscore are usually only available in debug builds of OpenLayers.  getArray() returns an OpenLayers collection which has getLength() and pop() methods.

```
if (map.getLayers().getLength() > 1) {
  map.getLayers().pop();
}
```

Comment: OK, this works also. It's magic? You don't call the array? You call the object and pop it?

Comment: Yes, the collection object supports getLength() and pop() https://openlayers.org/en/latest/apidoc/module-ol_Collection-Collection.html

Answer (score 0):

I have found it myself.  There is a getArray().

```
if (map.getLayers().getArray().length > 1) {
map.getLayers().getArray().pop();
}
```